# Socket.io broadcast only to the user who started the group

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets

Hey guys am trying to make a webrtc chat using socket. Io, and broadcast all the other clients stream to only the user who started the group, but all the other clients can get the stream of the user who started the group and not each other streams please I need help in fixing this

**My socket code**

```
io.on('connection',socket =>{
  socket.on('join-class',(classId,palsid)=>{
      socket.join(classId)
      socket.to(classId).broadcast.emit('user-connected',palsid)
      
      socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
          socket.to(classId).broadcast.emit('user-disconnect',palsid)
      })
  })
  
})

server.listen(4000, ()=>{
    console.log('server is running on port 4000')
})
```

**My frontend code**

```
 import React from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import Peer from 'peerjs'
import './ClassWall.css'
import { Modal, Button } from 'antd';
import img from '../../uploads/349-3498013_laptop-personal-computer-diagram-computer-icons-download-laptop-clipart.png'

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000/')


class LiveClass extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            userId :'',
            classStatus: '',
            videoSrc:'',
            visible: false
        }
    } 
    
    async componentDidMount(){
                
        //set the user id of logedin user
        const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid')
        const Myvideo = document.createElement('video')
        Myvideo.addEventListener('click',()=>{
            console.log(Myvideo)
        })
        Myvideo.muted = true

        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/Auth//UserID/id',{
                headers:{token:localStorage.token}
            })
            const Parse = await response.json()
            this.setState({userId:Parse})
        } catch (error) {
                        
        }
        //get user id to connect through peer
        const myPeer = new Peer(this.state.userId,{
            host: '/',
            port:4001
        })
        //connect and share video stream
        try {
            const peers = {}
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video:true,
                audio:true
            }).then(stream =>{
            addVideoStream(Myvideo,stream)
            
                myPeer.on('call',call=>{
                    call.answer(stream)
                    const video = document.createElement('video')
                    call.on('stream',userVideostream=>{
                        addVideoStream(video,userVideostream)
                    })
                })
            
                socket.on('user-connected',userId=>{
                    connectToNewUser(userId,stream)
                  console.log('newUser',userId)
                })
            })
            
            socket.on('user-disconnect', userId=>{
                if(peers[userId])peers[userId].close()
            })
            
            myPeer.on('open',id=>{
                socket.emit('join-class',this.props.match.params.id,id)
            })
            //get user stream and connect
            function connectToNewUser(userId,stream){
                const call  = myPeer.call(userId,stream)
                const video = document.createElement('video')
                video.setAttribute("class",`pointer`)
                video.addEventListener('click',()=>{
                    console.log(video)
                })
                    call.on('stream',userVideostream=>{
                        addVideoStream(video,userVideostream)
                    })
                call.on('close',()=>{
                    video.remove()
                })
            
                peers[userId]=call
            }
            
            //Add video stream
            function addVideoStream(video,stream){
                const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid')
                video.srcObject = stream
                video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () =>{
                    video.play()
                })
                videoGrid.append(video)
            }
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error',error)    
        }
        this.checkIfClassTrue()   
    }

    //check if its class
    checkIfClassTrue = async()=>{
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:4000/liveclass/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
        const Parse = await response.json()
        this.setState({classStatus:Parse})
    }
 
    //modal
    showModal = () => {
        this.setState({
          visible: true,
        });
      };
    
      handleOk = e => {
        console.log(e);
        this.setState({
          visible: false,
        });
      };
    
      handleCancel = e => {
        console.log(e);
        this.setState({
          visible: false,
        });
      };
    
   
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
               {
                   this.state.classStatus === 'Not found'?
                   'not found':
                   <div>
                       
                       <div id="video-grid">
                                {/* <img src={img}/> */}
                            </div>
                            <Button type="primary" onClick={this.showModal}>
                        Open Modal
                        </Button>
                        <Modal
                        title="Basic Modal"
                        visible={this.state.visible}
                        onOk={this.handleOk}
                        onCancel={this.handleCancel}
                        >
                        
                        </Modal>
                   </div>
               }
            </div>
        )
    }
    }

export default LiveClass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use redis or other cache database to store the room initiators' `socketId` and then send the message specifically to that user with `io.to(socketId).emit()`. So, on connection, you can store the initiators' `socketId` in redis as key-value `classId: socketId`. Then fetch the `socketId` by `classId` every time you need to send something to that specific client.